# Control - Number threads based on requirement

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have scenario where i need to invoke threads based on throughput values for the same sampler.
I am planning to use ultimate thread group where first group starts with 2 users and files 100 requests
and second group starts with 5 users fires with 300 requests.

Is there a way we can use if controller to write condition saying if Number of threads equal to   number then enter otherwise skip.

Or Suggest me if there is any other way we can implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) instead, it can be combined with [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) so if the current number of threads won't be sufficient in order to reach and maintain the desired number of hits per second - the timer will initiate kicking off more extra threads.

If you want to get the number of active threads in the If Controller - you can consider using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) for this, the number of threads can be checked as follows:

```
ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumberOfThreads()
```